# Cordova 3.0, Android Library Project

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

How to link Android Library project to the Android project using Cordoava 3.0? Thus, while building application via Cordova command line, this library project should be linked automatically.

Any solutions or references to external sites is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get any standard protocol to do this. I have created Android Dependency folder at the level folder 'platforms' exist. And placed the Android Library project over there and referenced it in Android Project with relative path in Android Project project.properties